# Start/stop setTimeout with a button & prevent counting faster with more clicks

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

I am working with JavaScript and I use a setTimeout function in order to count up. Here is my code...

```html
<button id="star">Start</button>
<p id="time">0</p>
```

```js
var timeEl = 0;

function start() {
    time();
}

function time() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        timeEl = timeEl + .1;
        timeEnd = timeEl.toFixed(1);
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeEnd;
        time();
    }, 100);
}

var el = document.getElementById("star");
el.addEventListener("click", star, false);
```

1. How do I get my setTimeout function to start on stop when I click on the button
2. How to prevent my counting from going faster the more times I click on the button.

I have included my JSFiddle below!
https://jsfiddle.net/pb4759jh68/0618eLoe/

Comment: You can simplifiy code by using `setInterval`

Comment: you can use `setInterval` for recursion and `clearInterval` to stop the recursion loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop a timer you can use `clearTimeout()`, but it does require the id of the timer created with `setTimeout()`.  The call to `setTimeout()` now saves the timer id in `timeOut` and then checks the contents of `timeOut` in `start()` to see whether a timer is currently running.  If a timer is running then `timeOut` is used in `clearTimeout(timeOut);`.

```
var timeEl = 0;
var timeOut = null;
function start()
{
  if(timeOut !== null){
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    timeOut = null;
  }else{
    time();
  }
}
function time()
{
  timeOut = setTimeout(function()
  {
    timeEl = timeEl + .1;
    timeEnd = timeEl.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeEnd;
    time();
  }, 100);
}

var el = document.getElementById("star");
el.addEventListener("click", start, false);
```

I hope this code clears the issue

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vpdvs5vq/)

The same can be achieved using setInterval and clearInterval. Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xg1o3fmv/)

Comment: Thanks. I took it a little further to get data as well. https://jsfiddle.net/vr_driver/qbn0s2mg/24/

Answer (score 1):

Every time the button is pressed, you get a second copy of your timer running, which is advancing your time faster.

```
var el = document.getElementById("star");
el.addEventListener("click", start, false);
```

I would recommend something like this:

```
var timerId = 0;
var timeEl = 0;
function start()
{
  time();
}
function time()
{
  timerId = setTimeout(function()
  {
    timeEl = timeEl + .1;
    timeEnd = timeEl.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeEnd;
    time();
  }, 100);
}

var el = document.getElementById("star");
el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (timerId !== 0) {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerId = 0;
  } else {
    start();
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel a previously set timeout with `clearTimeout` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

try this
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/gxL7j5er/)

```
var timeEl = 0,timer;
function start()
{
  time();
}
function time()
{
document.getElementById("star").disabled=true;
  timer=setTimeout(function()
  {
    timeEl = timeEl + .1;
    timeEnd = timeEl.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeEnd;
    time();
  }, 100);
}

function stop(){
document.getElementById("star").disabled=false;
clearTimeout(timer);
}

var el = document.getElementById("star");
el.addEventListener("click", start, false);
var elstop = document.getElementById("stop");
elstop.addEventListener("click", stop, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a boolean that states if the counting is already running :

https://jsfiddle.net/0618eLoe/3/

```
var timeEl = 0;
var isStarted = false;
function startStop()
{
  if (!isStarted) {
    isStarted = true;
    time();
  } else {
    isStarted = false;
  }
}
function time()
{
  if (!isStarted) return;

  setTimeout(function()
  {
    timeEl = timeEl + .1;
    timeEnd = timeEl.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeEnd;
    time();
  }, 100);
}

var el = document.getElementById("star");
el.addEventListener("click", startStop, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timeEl = 0,g;
function start()
{
if(g){
 clearTimeout(g);
  timeEl = 0;
}
  time();
}
function time()
{
  g=setTimeout(function()
  {
    timeEl = timeEl + .1;
    timeEnd = timeEl.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeEnd;
    time();
  }, 100);
}

var el = document.getElementById("star");
el.addEventListener("click", start, false);
```

```
tell me what else would you need. or it implements your specification. here button click will start the timer from 0 again.
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jq4adex8/)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple solution using `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

```
var time = 0.0;
var view = document.getElementById('time');
var running = false;
var repeat;

function start(){
    if(running){
        return;
    }
    running = true;
    repeat = setInterval(increment, 100);
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(repeat);
    running = false;
}

function increment(){
        time += 0.1;
        view.innerText = time.toFixed(1);
}
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/m7bmc2uj/