# Issue with javascript timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I wrote a timer code via JavaScript. I want to stop this timer when I click on a button, and restart it by double clicking the same button, however, it currently only works once.

Here is the code:

```js
let pElement = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(pElement);

let liveTimer = () => {
  let date = new Date();
  let onlineTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();

  pElement.innerHTML = onlineTime;
};

let setI = setInterval(liveTimer, 1000);

function stopTime() {
  clearInterval(setI);
}

function startTimer() {
  setInterval(liveTimer, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stopTime()" ondblclick="startTimer()">click me</button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733692/start-stop-settimeout-with-a-button-prevent-counting-faster-with-more-clicks

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set the interval-Id the second time you are calling `setInterval` inside the `startTimer` function.

Just because you set the value here `let setI= setInterval(liveTimer,1000);`, doesn't mean that the value will get refreshed when you do `setInterval(liveTimer,1000);`. This will return a different value that you need to store inside a variable.

```js
let pElement = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(pElement);


let liveTimer = () => {
  let date = new Date();

  let onlineTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();

  pElement.innerHTML = onlineTime;

};

let setI = setInterval(liveTimer, 1000);

function stopTime() {
  clearInterval(setI);
}


function startTimer() {
  setI = setInterval(liveTimer, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stopTime()" ondblclick="startTimer()">click me</button>
```

Comment: Come to think of it, it is a typo-type question and can be closed

Comment: I really appreciate it

Comment: @mplungjan Just because the solution sounds obvious once its been stated, doesn't mean that the problem was a typo. I would say that problem was closer to a syntax error in the sense that the user didn't know that value doesn't get bound to the interval.

Comment: There is no "close as syntax error" to choose. Typo-type covers this too

Comment: @mplungjan Why would it fall under the same category? The problem may have been caused by lack of JavaScript knowledge (without any offense to the OP). Isn't this one of the main reason why SO exists?

Comment: Sure, but a comment had been enough. - Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733692/start-stop-settimeout-with-a-button-prevent-counting-faster-with-more-clicks

Comment: @mplungjan Fair enough.